# lua line numbers after multiple calls to loadbuffer

Tags: lua, numbers, line

I load two strings with loadbuffer into one lua_state.

```
if( luaL_loadbuffer( L, str.c_str(), str.size(), "line") != 0 )
{
    printf( "%s\n", lua_tostring ((lua_State *)L, -1));
}
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

if( luaL_loadbuffer( L, str2.c_str(), str2.size(), "line2") != 0 )
{
    printf( "%s\n", lua_tostring ((lua_State *)L, -1));
}
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
```

For example:

```
function f ()


    print( "Hello World!")
end
```

and

```
function g ()

    f(
end
```

The forgotten `)` in the second string throws an error:

```
[string "line2"]:9: unexpected Symbol
```

But **9** is the line number from string 1 plus string 2. The line number should be 3.

Is there a way to reset the line number counter before call to loadbuffer?

Comment: There should be no need to reset the line number. Two `luaL_loadbuffer` should no interfere with each other. You'll have to show us the contents of `str` and `str2`.

Comment: And the line number of the error actually increases if you put more new lines in str1?

Comment: The contents of str and str2 is already shown. Yes, the line number increases adding lines to str.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this link describes your situation:
http://www.corsix.org/content/common-lua-pitfall-loading-code

You are loading two chunks of information, calling the chunks will put them consecutive into the global table. The `lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);` is not calling your `f()` and `g()`, but is constructing your lua code sequential.

Your code could possibly be simplified to:

```
if (luaL_dostring(L, str.c_str()))
{
    printf("%s\n", lua_tostring (L, -1));
}
if (luaL_dostring(L, str2.c_str()));
{
    printf("%s\n", lua_tostring (L, -1));
}
```

which also protects against calling a chunk when it fails to load;

Comment: This is good observation but it does not explain what the OP saw. His code is *not* "constructing lua code sequential".

Comment: It returns line 9 as error source. Same like using loadbuffer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right Enigma, the code from str2 is appended consecutive. A breakpoint in

```
static void statement (LexState *ls) {
```

in lparser.cpp shows LexState.linenumber to be 5 and 7 for str, and 5, 7, 14 and 16 for str2.
So str is lexed and added to the VM twice.
I will find a different way to put a script made of multiple files into one VM.

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone would need it too.

Add this function to lauxlib.h

```
LUALIB_API int (luaL_loadbuffers) (lua_State *L, size_t count, const char **buff, size_t *sz,
                                   const char **name, const char *mode);
```

and to lauxlib.c

```
#include"lzio.h"
#include"ldo.h"
#include"ltable.h"
#include"lgc.h"
LUALIB_API int luaL_loadbuffers (lua_State *L, size_t count, const char **buff, size_t *sz,
                                   const char **name, const char *mode)
{
    ZIO z;
    int status;

    int i;

    for( i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        LoadS ls;
        ls.s = buff[i];
        ls.size = sz[i];

        lua_lock(L);

        luaZ_init(L, &z, getS, &ls);
        status = luaD_protectedparser(L, &z, name[i], mode);

        if (status == LUA_OK) {  /* no errors? */
            LClosure *f = clLvalue(L->top - 1);  /* get newly created function */
            if (f->nupvalues == 1) {  /* does it have one upvalue? */

                /* get global table from registry */
                Table *reg = hvalue(&G(L)->l_registry);
                const TValue *gt = luaH_getint(reg, LUA_RIDX_GLOBALS);
                /* set global table as 1st upvalue of 'f' (may be LUA_ENV) */
                setobj(L, f->upvals[0]->v, gt);
                luaC_barrier(L, f->upvals[0], gt);


            } // == 1

            lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        lua_unlock(L);

        if( status != LUA_OK )
            break;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Every string/file gets its own line numnbering.
It is just a copy, almost, of lua_load in lapi.c. So easy to adjust in a new release of LUA.